# How to get task data with parent task name from same table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am using MySQL database to store task and sub-task in a project. For parent task I am sending 0 and for sub-task parent_id. Iam saving all records in same table. Now I want to listing them so I am using join to get the data. My join query is

```
$project_tasks = DB::table('project_tasks as subTask')
        ->leftjoin('project_tasks ptask', 'ptask.id', '=', 'subTask.parent_id')
        ->select('subTask.*','ptask.title as parent_title')
        ->get();
```

But I am getting error in this query.

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_name.project_tasks ptask' doesn't exist
```

how can I get parent name with child record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 project_tasks as ptask
```

try if this works

Comment: I used the same but got error don't know what I missed now it's. Thanks